# Registration flow is failing in jmeter and application throws You cannot proceed with such operation, your reCaptcha reputation is too low. Error

Tags: jmeter, registration

I am using `Jmeter` to automate the registration flow of the application.

I have used HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and recorded the entire application flow. Once I fill the form and hit Register Button. The application is giving me

```
You cannot proceed with such operation, your reCaptcha reputation is too low.
```

and hence registration is not successful.

The Registration form also uses 3 hidden fields and form_key is dynamic and other 2 is empty. I have given the Request payload of those 3 hidden fields

```
-----------------------------285644297641549410313962484796
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_key"

ytIteIXb0UyXcoPf

-----------------------------285644297641549410313962484796
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_url"


-----------------------------285644297641549410313962484796
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="error_url"
```

I am stuck as I cant proceed with the registration flow itself.
Please help me with the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/) is one of implementations of [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) which stands for `Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart` so there is nothing you can do about it using JMeter.

You should disable this CAPTCHA check for the duration of the load test because your test should focus **solely on your application functionality** so you need to exclude at least this CAPTCHA challenge as well as [any other external resources (3rd-party scripts, fonts, banners, images, videos, etc.) from your load test scope](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)

With regards to these "hidden" fields - they need to be properly [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) before replaying.